# JavaScript method does not refresh the select option as expected based on the day of week?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below javascript method `setDayOfWeek()` does not seem to work for me. All i am doing is trying to get the day based on the date and based on the day number refresh the select option using jquery it seems to be behaving odd just shows Monday-Friday but never Saturday or Sunday ?

```
 function setDayOfWeek(){

 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getDay()

 var dayofweek= parseInt(n);
 alert(dayofweek);

 if(dayofweek > 0 && dayofweek < 6)

    alert("Weekday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Weekday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }

 if(dayofweek == 0){

    alert("Sunday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Sunday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }


 if(dayofweek == 6){

    alert("Saturday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Saturday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }
```

.

```
 <select name="select-choice-dayofweek" id="select-choice-dayofweek" >
                        <option value="">Day Of the Week</option>
                        <option value="Weekday">Monday-Friday</option>
                        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/6AsrH/) for me, without `$('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");`s though. Added also a missing curly bracket. What is `.selectmenu()`, I couldn't find it from jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/xpJ7J/)**

```
function setDayOfWeek(){

 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getDay()

 var dayofweek= parseInt(n);
 alert(dayofweek);

 if(dayofweek > 0 && dayofweek < 6){

    alert("Weekday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Weekday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }

 if(dayofweek == 0){

    alert("Sunday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Sunday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }


 if(dayofweek == 6){

    alert("Saturday");
    $("#select-choice-dayofweek").val('Saturday');
    $('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");

 }
}
setDayOfWeek();
```

You didn't close the function's closing brace. You also need to call the function to execute it. Everything seems to work the way you wanted. Still I'm confused, what does `$('#select-choice-dayofweek').selectmenu("refresh");` mean?

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it satisfies the need.

Answer (score 0):

you missed this "{" in this line

> if(dayofweek > 0 && dayofweek < 6){